# How do I make it where you can only be between ages 15 and 80 when inputting date of birth

Tags: javascript, html

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = "0" + dd;
  }

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
  }

  minYear = yyyy - 80; //Calculate Minimun Age (<80)
  maxYear = yyyy - 18; //Calculate Maximum Age (>18)

  var min = minYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
  var max = maxYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("min", min);
  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("max", max);
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
  <input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="trip-start" value="2021-10-02" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? My JavaScript isn't working. It only works as inline JavaScript but for some reason it nullifies my other JavaScript code and still doesn't work, so I made a separate external JS file to test it but it doesn't work.

Note: It cannot be inline JavaScript.

Comment: What isn't working? Looks like it works to me

Comment: I would suggest using addEventListener, but your code still works: `window.addEventListener("load", function() { ... });`

Comment: My JavaScript isn't working. What I put up there is all I've got on my JavaScript and HTML files respectively, nothing else. I'm quite new to JavaScript so I can't point out the mistake.

Comment: WHAT does not work? If I hit submit in Chrome, I am told to enter a date from 2003. So the script works, your title description is off 3 years

Comment: It does not limit the the date I can choose. I can choose a date and click submit just fine but it doesn't restrict the date. I am aware of the error where it's 3 years off.

Comment: Never mind, I've solved it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what did you solve. What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you have to set event listener

```
  function getEvent(){
var age = getElementById("start").value;
if(age<18 || age> 80){
 console.log("age should be between 18 and 80")
}
}
<input type"submit" onclick="getEvent()" name="click here">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 